# Angular reactive controls value is not updated correctly

Tags: typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular8

i am returning date from this function , why this function also update the StartDate controls value,
for ex: if StartDate is 15Dec2019 and i want to return 17Dec2019 , and this method returning correct value but it also update the StartDate control value with returning date from the function.

this value should not be updated inside this function , here i am getting control value not updaing.**this.createRecord.controls['StartDate'].value**

```
addDays(date: Date, days: number): Date {
date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
return date;}



GetDueDate(): Date {
#region Recurring End Type -> No Of Occurences
debugger;
const dtStart: Date = this.createRecord.controls['StartDate'].value;
let returnDate: Date;
let dtEnd: Date = dtStart;
let FrequencyId: number = +this.createRecord.controls['FrequencyId'].value;
for (let i = 1; i < +this.createRecord.controls['Occurances'].value; i++)
{
  //#region Next Date Calculation

  if (FrequencyId == 1) {
    dtEnd = this.addDays(dtStart, 1);//dtStart.(1);
  }
  else if (FrequencyId == 2) {
    dtEnd = this.addDays(dtStart, 2);
  }
  else if (FrequencyId == 3) {
    dtEnd = this.addDays(dtStart, 15);
  }
  else if (FrequencyId == 4) {
    dtEnd = this.addMonths(dtStart,4);
  }
  else if (FrequencyId == 5) {
    dtEnd = this.addMonths(dtStart, 3);
  }
  else if (FrequencyId == 6) {
    dtEnd = this.addMonths(dtStart, 6);
  }
  else if (FrequencyId == 7) {
    dtEnd = this.addYears(dtStart, 1);
  }
 //#endregion

  returnDate = dtEnd;
}

//#endregion
return returnDate;
```

Comment: Because you have a single Date object used for both, and muted using setDate(). Never, ever, ever call setDate(). Treat Date as an immutable class. Create a copy when you need another value.

Answer (score 1):

Date is mutable. You should create new Date.

```
const addDays = (date: Date, days: number): Date => {
    const newDate = new Date(date.getTime())
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + days);
    return newDate;
}
const date = new Date();
const after2Days = addDays(date, 2);
console.log('date:',date);
console.log('after2Days:',after2Days);
```